# Perl & PHP project requirement

Tags: php, perl, projects, requirements

I have learned Perl and PHP.So I want to do simple real time project in this by that I can improve my knowledge in Perl and PHP.

Can anyone suggest me any requirements.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a website where users can catalog their collection of any set of items. It really helps if you have a hobby where you collect something so you have something you are interested in:  My CDs, my comics, my books, etc. Typically then you have to figure out how to store data to represent real world objects and relate multiple concepts, such as book, category, and author.  You can add pictures to play with everything from image resizing to storing items in Amazon S3 buckets.  If the objects are things you do something with (such as read or listen to) you can also create a interaction logging system.  Making data models to allow users to catalog not only their collections but their habits of interacting with them (graphs!) should provide plenty of things to code.

Answer (score 2):

Find a [free/open source project](http://freshmeat.net) that interests you and get involved. Most post clear coding standards and you can find plenty of enjoyable tasks to do in their bug tracker. Another good place to find a project to get involved with is [OpenHatch](http://openhatch.org/).

You will benefit from peer review of your code as well as the knowledge of more experienced developers. You will also demonstrate to potential employers that you work well with others, communicate effectively and enjoy programming in your spare time.